# feed appearing different in the three main browsers

Tags: feed

My blog feed appears diffenently in the three main browsers:

- in IExplorer it is perfect;
- in Chrome it appears as a xml file in source view
- in Firefox it appears like the result list from a search in the blog
  (first lines of the posts without any html formatting)

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your feed is just an XML file.  If you try to look at a feed in a web browser, each browser shows the feed in a different way.  Some will just show the raw XML code, and others will try to display something more human-readable and meaningful to an end user.  Sometimes the browser will even offer some choices for subscribing to the feed.  But it is up to the browser.

The feed isn't really for web browsers anyway; it is intended to be read by a news reader, which will read the XML file and show you each post in whichever way is appropriate for the news reader you are using.

Answer (score 2):

There is no stylesheet associated with the feed. Each browser will use its own default style for it.

You can add a custom stylesheet via the hooks `atom_head` or `rss2_head`. But that’s not needed usually, because most readers will use a dedicated feed reader to view your feed.